# How get ROWs in product Custom option (drop-down)?

Tags: custom-options

[image]

Need get Sub options with id 38, 39
Easy get options $_product->getOptions() but how get sub options (row) ?

Comment: are want the data using options select field 38,39?

Comment: yes.., but how?

Comment: $productOptionValue = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option_value')->load($valueId);

Comment: are you want all value of option Select your service using it id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get Data of Options That is `Select your Service` in your case
you can do like this

`$products   = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('1');`  **//product Id with custom options**

```
$option = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option')->getProductOptionCollection($product);
foreach($option as $o){
 print_r($o->getData());   
}
```

and to get value Data that is Row 38 and 39 in your case do it like this

`$products   = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('1');`  **//product Id with custom options**

```
$option = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option')->getProductOptionCollection($product);
foreach ($option as $o) {
  print_r($o->getData());      
  $values = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_option_value')->getValuesCollection($o);
  foreach($values as $value){
    print_r($value->getData());
  }
}
```

and you will have it all.

Answer (score 1):

You ca get the details by **Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option_value')**
Please use this

```
$productOptionValue = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option_value')->load($valueId);
```

$valueId=38;

Also for **getting option value using option** id,use

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_option_value_collection')
            ->addFieldToFilter('option_id', $optionId)
            ->getValues($CurrentStoreId);
```

**get Value ids by Option**

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_option_value_collection')
            ->addFieldToFilter('option_id', $option_id)
            ->getValuesByOption($optionIds, $store_id);
```

Comment: 38 and 39 only as an example

Comment: i cannot understand what you want?

Comment: getValues in this option. Snx.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved

```
foreach ($_product->getOptions() as $option) {
    $option->getValues()
}
```